# Six-piece, two-tone wooden puzzle

Tags: three-dimensional

[image: Picture of two tone, three dimensional wooden puzzle]

We've had this puzzle for ages and I can't find a solution anywhere. I have vague memories of it being a cross but can't be sure.

I've searched everywhere online and in the house for a solution, can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide a scaleable, 3D, user-friendly, javascript applet that provides us with an interactive GUI so that we may rotate/move each piece with reckless abandon?

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd do that.

Comment: Is there any holes we can't see in the white pieces ?

Comment: No. They're all visible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like this puzzle :

[image]

And the solution that comes with the puzzle can be found here : http://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~storer/JimPuzzles/ZPAGES/zzz6PieceNSThreePieces.html

[image]

Here is a step by step solution I made using [Burr Tools](http://burrtools.sourceforge.net/). It uses color for more clarity.

[image: six pieces made with burr tools]
[image: step by step solution made with burr tools]

I hope this helps you finally solve this puzzle !

Comment: That's great thank you. It's literally been about 10 years and I couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks so much!